# QJsonObject chained assignment produces unexpected results

Tags: c++, qt, assignment-operator, qjson, qjsonobject

When I assign the same value to two different non-existent keys in QJsonObject, I'm getting an unexpected result:

```
json["first"] = json["second"] = "world!";
```

As far as I know, this code should add two new keys `first` and `second`, both with a value of `world!`.
Instead the `first` has a value of another element that previously existed in that `QJsonObject`, while `second` actually has the right value of `world!`.
When I separate those two assignments:

```
json["first"]  = "world!";
json["second"] = "world!";
```

it works correctly, but how does that make a difference?

Actual (chained) output: `QJsonObject({"first":"Hello","foo":"Hello","second":"world!"})`

Expected (separate) output: `QJsonObject({"first":"world!","foo":"Hello","second":"world!"})`

Full source code:

```
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QJsonObject json {
        {"foo", "Hello"}
    };

    json["first"] = json["second"] = "world!";

    qDebug() << json;

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on Qt 5.15.2 MinGW 8.1.0 x64 and Qt 6.3.2 MinGW 11.2.0 x64 in both debug and release builds, both on Windows.